# AEM 6.3 : Sling Servlet registered with resourceType

Tags: javascript, java, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

I have created a Sling servlet that is being called using AJAX. Here is the servlet code:

```
package com.aem.sites.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.Designate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.aem.sites.interfaces.SearchConfiguration;


@Component(
immediate = true,
service = Servlet.class,
configurationPid = "com.aem.sites.servlets.SearchServlet",
property = {
        "sling.servlet.methods=get", 
        "sling.servlet.selectors=search",
        "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=aemsite-project/components/structure/page",
        "sling.servlet.extensions=html"     
}
        )
@Designate(ocd=SearchConfiguration.class)
public class SearchServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet  {

     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The Constant logger. */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest req,
                final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("********************************inside search servlet:::do get*****************************************");
    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void Activate(SearchConfiguration config) {
        logger.info("********************************inside search servlet*****************************************");
    }

}


package com.aem.sites.interfaces;

import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.ObjectClassDefinition;

@ObjectClassDefinition(name="Search Configuration")
public @interface SearchConfiguration {

    @AttributeDefinition(
            name = "Enable",
            description = "Sample boolean property"
        )
        boolean enabled() default false;

}
```

[image]

This is the js file :

```
$('#search-input input').keydown(function(event) {
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode :event.which);
    if(keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('inside key event');
        var searchterm = $("#search-input input").val();
        console.log('value of search term is '+searchterm);
        //$("searchForm").submit();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/content/aemsite/en/results.search.html?q="+searchterm,
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    }

});
```

For some reason, the servlet isn't being called. I have followed these examples:

https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-osgi-annotation-demo/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/nateyolles/aem/osgiannotationdemo/core/servlets/SampleOsgiServlet.java

http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/sling-servlet-in-aem/

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

It causes that DS is implemented as case sensitive for value of 'sling.servlet.methods'. You can resolve it by update from "sling.servlet.methods=get" to "sling.servlet.methods=GET".

```
package com.aem63.features.core.components.search;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881339/aem-6-3-sling-servlet-registered-with-resourcetype
 */

@Component(service = Servlet.class,
        immediate = true,
        configurationPid = "com.aem63.features.core.components.search.SearchServlet",
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Simple Demo Servlet",
                "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=" + "sling/servlet/default",
                "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "search",
                "sling.servlet.extensions=" + "data"

        })
public class SearchServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * The Constant logger.
     */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest req,
                         final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("********************************inside search servlet:::do get*****************************************");
    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void Activate(SearchConfiguration config) {
        logger.info("********************************inside search servlet*****************************************");
    }

}
```

Demo page: http://localhost:4502/content/aem63-features/en/jcr:content/.en.txt